# What's the best way to test an iPhone game for iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I've developed a game for the iPhone... on my iPhone.  When I submitted it to the store I marked it as "iPhone only".  Now I'm getting emails asking "Why not iPod touch?".

The game doesn't use any iPhone only features btw.  So...

I'd like to test it on an actual iPod Touch to be sure it works.  Is this really necessary?

If so do developers just go out and buy an iPod touch to test on?  haha... guess this is pretty obvious :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you haven't used obvious features not in the touch you should be fine. I did development on an iPhone application that we didn't test on a touch until a couple days before it was submitted to the store. There wasn't anything that needed to be changed.

Comment: Why not ask any of your users having an iPod? Maybe they want to do some beta-testing.